# json - query with conditions

Tags: json, jq

I have following json:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "profile1",
  "userId": "0",
  "groupId": "3",
  "attributes": [
    {
      "id": "104",
      "name": "Enable",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": "105",
      "name": "TargetNode",
      "value": "system1"
    },
    {
      "id": "106",
      "name": "Timeout",
      "value": "30"
    }
  ],
  "xconns": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "locked": false,
      "attributeList": [
        {
          "id": "101",
          "name": "Lgrp",
          "value": "1"
        },
        {
          "id": "102",
          "name": "IsRem",
          "value": "1"
        },
        {
          "id": "103",
          "name": "Media",
          "value": "1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "locked": false,
      "attributeList": [
        {
          "id": "101",
          "name": "Lgrp",
          "value": "1"
        },
        {
          "id": "102",
          "name": "IsRem",
          "value": "1"
        },
        {
          "id": "103",
          "name": "Media",
          "value": "1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "locked": false,
      "attributeList": [
        {
          "id": "101",
          "name": "Lgrp",
          "value": "1"
        },
        {
          "id": "102",
          "name": "IsRem",
          "value": "1"
        },
        {
          "id": "103",
          "name": "Media",
          "value": "1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
{
  "id": "2",
  "name": "profile2",
  "userId": "7",
  "groupId": "0",
  "attributes": [
    {
      "id": "104",
      "name": "Enable",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": "105",
      "name": "TargetNode",
      "value": "system2"
    },
    {
      "id": "106",
      "name": "Timeout",
      "value": "30"
    }
  ],
  "xconns": [
    {
      "id": "2",
      "locked": false,
      "attributeList": [
        {
          "id": "101",
          "name": "Lgrp",
          "value": "1"
        },
        {
          "id": "102",
          "name": "IsRem",
          "value": "1"
        },
        {
          "id": "103",
          "name": "Media",
          "value": "1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "locked": false,
      "attributeList": [
        {
          "id": "101",
          "name": "Lgrp",
          "value": "1"
        },
        {
          "id": "102",
          "name": "IsRem",
          "value": "1"
        },
        {
          "id": "103",
          "name": "Media",
          "value": "1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "locked": false,
      "attributeList": [
        {
          "id": "101",
          "name": "Lgrp",
          "value": "1"
        },
        {
          "id": "102",
          "name": "IsRem",
          "value": "1"
        },
        {
          "id": "103",
          "name": "Media",
          "value": "1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I can filter following:

```
$ jq -r 'select([.attributes[] | .name == "TargetNode" ] | any ) | [{userId, groupId, id, name}] | .[] | if (.userId == "0") then del(.userId) else . end | if (.groupId == "0") then del(.groupId) else . end | to_entries | map("\(.key | ascii_upcase):\(.value)") | @tsv' file.json
GROUPID:3       ID:1    NAME:profile1
USERID:7        ID:2    NAME:profile2
```

I need to add also value of TargetNode:

```
GROUPID:3       ID:1    NAME:profile1    TARGETNODE:system1
USERID:7        ID:2    NAME:profile2    TARGETNODE:system2
```

is there a way to include it in 
[{userId, groupId, id, name, TargetNode}] 
to get the value of TargetNode and not null?

GROUPID:3       ID:1    NAME:profile1   TARGETNODE:null

USERID:7        ID:2    NAME:profile2   TARGETNODE:null

Update:
the solution provided by RomanPerekhrest is nearly ok, but there is one issue because the json file in real is much bigger, there are more attrobutes in "main secttion", for example:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "profile1",
  "userId": "0",
  "groupId": "3",
  "attrib101": "A",
  "attrib102": "B",
  "attributes": [
...
...
```

it is cousing that RomanPerekhrest's jq filter returns too much...
how to rid of them too?

```
ID:1    NAME:profile1   GROUPID:3   ATTRIB101:A     ATTRIB102:B TARGETNODE:system1
ID:2    NAME:profile2   USERID:7    ATTRIB101:C     ATTRIB102:D TARGETNODE:system2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`jq`** solution:

```
jq -r '.attributes |= map(select(.name == "TargetNode")) 
       | if (.attributes | length != 0) then .targetNode = .attributes[0].value else . end 
       | if (.userId == "0") then del(.userId) else . end 
       | if (.groupId == "0") then del(.groupId) else . end 
       | del(.attributes, .xconns) | to_entries 
       | map("\(.key | ascii_upcase):\(.value)") | @tsv' file.json
```

If an object with `"name": "TargetNode"` pair not exists - `TARGETNODE` won't be added into resulting structure

The output:

```
ID:1    NAME:profile1   GROUPID:3   TARGETNODE:system1
ID:2    NAME:profile2   USERID:7    TARGETNODE:system2
```

Comment: thank you, it works perfectly, please ignore my update as you already answered it to:        | del(.attributes, .xconns, .startOrder, .attrib101, .attrib102) | to_entries

Comment: How to add order change to this filter to get on output for example:
ID:1 TARGETNODE:system1 GROUPID:3 NAME:profile1

Comment: @Chris, we can't move dynamic/optional fields: `TARGETNODE` is optional + `GROUPID` and `USERID` are mutually exclusive